# Symfony adding extra fields by CreateAction

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a createAction for a Symfony request.

How can I add some values in another entity, by creating a new Entity value.

See the following foreach part; whats wrong with it?

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new FooType();
    $form = $this->createForm(new FooTypeType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('OtherBundle:Lists')->findAll();
        foreach($entities as $list){

            $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $listValue = new ListValue();
            $listValue->setSpecification( new ListsType(), $list );

            $manager->persist($listValue);
            $manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('foo_foobar_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
```

Comment: What is ListType and ListsType ?! explain what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

if you have a proper association mapping between your entities and use Doctrine's **persist** option for the **cascade** operation you won't have to persist your related entities explicitly.

You can in this case ommit

```
$manager->persist($listValue);
```

Furthermore for performance reasons make sure you **flush** your entityManager **only once** - you don't need to flush more than once often except in case you need the auto-generated ID of a newly persisted entity!

create a new method in your repository ( addListsToEntity() ) or in a manager class for adding your lists!